# Javers - Custom comparator for generic list - GENERIC_TYPE_NOT_PARAMETRIZED

Tags: java, javers

I would like to compare a generic list which is defined in abstract class in object which inherits from that class, the thing is that I would like to implement custom comparator for that list's objects.

here is code of the abstract class:

```
class A<T extends GenericT, DM extends SomeOtherGeneric>{
private List<T> genericsT = new ArrayList()<>;
private DM otherGeneric;
}
```

And here you can find class which I am comparing explicitly:

```
class ExtendsA extends A<ImplementationOfT, ImplementationOfOther>{
}
```

what I am trying to do is to have registered such comparators:

```
 javers.registerCustomType(ImplementationOfOther.class, new ImplementationOfOtherComparator()); // this one works as expected
 javers.registerCustomType(ImplementationOfA.class, new ImplementationOfAComparator()); //this one is not called
```

So as you can see list genericsT is not compared in the way I would like to have it.

Here is also a warning which I get from javers:

```
09:40:26.945 [main] WARN org.javers.core.diff.appenders.CorePropertyChangeAppender - Unknown item type in 
Set property: Field ListAsSetType:List<T> genericsT , declared in A. Defaulting to Object, see 
CorePropertyChangeAppender.GENERIC_TYPE_NOT_PARAMETRIZED
```

Is there any possibility to add custom comparator for implementation of `ImplementationOfT` which will be comparing list's elements `genericsT` when class `ExtendsA` is compared?

**EDIT**:
Looks like I can use `javers.compareCollections(a.getGenericsT(), b.getGenericsT(), ImplementationOfT.class)` 
and mark the collection with `@DiffIgnore`
but change's affectedCoID gives me `org.javers.core.graph.LiveGraphFactory$ListWrapper`
Is there any way to set there my custom name?

Answer (score 0):

Javers doesn't support all possible generic types in Java, there are limitations where things are getting too complex. Push your case here https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/cases then I will check why it doesn't work and will try to find a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyway I've decided to use new value object for my collections, where I can name my list like I want and specify the type of the collections.